# How to send email attachments/small files using WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I want to ask you about sending files using WCF.
I want to implement service, to send fax and emails. My case looks like that:

- The service will be hosted in windows service.
- I would like to make this service visible on the local network only. (So I will probably use netTcpBinding)
- and It will be great, when a customer who wants to send a fax or send email with attachments, will have to use only the "SendFax" function with specific parameters. I mean..  How to do that, so it would be very simple for client?
- I think the biggest attachment could be up to 20MB, I don't know how it looks like in case of a fax. But I think it will be MS Word file, so 20MB will upper limit.

I want to ask you how to implement, the server-side part of WCF service? 
Use buffered upload or streamed upload ? 
Could you give me a link to good example or article ?

Any help will be great, 
Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad and rather non-specific question.  What you want to do is achievable via WCF.  I suggest you google to see if there any articles out there that address your specific design criteria, or narrow the scope of your question to be more in-line with SO guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WCF service endpoint can accept a byte array of variable sizes so it shouldn't be a problem for a client to send a pdf,word, etc document as a byte[] to the service.  The default netTcpBinding settings will need to be adjusted to accomodate the large file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows service will host your WCF endpoint (e.g., SendDocument()).

The service's implementation of this method will use the standard **System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient** class to send the email. See the MSDN documentation for [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) and especially the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class, which among other things has an Attachments property you can use.

Comment: Actually.. I was asking about WCF part of that issue. Specially uploading file. How to do that, so it would be very simple for client?

Comment: What type of clients do you have? Custom applications that use your API, or do you want to provide a web site for your users to upload files and email/fax them? If it is the later then you need to look at a web application rather than a Windows Service.

Comment: WCF will be hosted in Windows Service - that is for sure. And clients will be windows applications, working in the same local network. This is my main scenario.